# When a bound property gets a input?

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps, .net-6.0, winui-3

Currently im learning to build windows apps with mvvm with the Template Studio. I added a SettingsPage what contains some elements like:

```
<StackPanel x:Name="ContentArea">
        <CommandBar Background="Transparent" OverflowButtonVisibility="Collapsed">
            <AppBarButton Click="BtnSave_Click" Icon="Save" />          
        </CommandBar>
        <Pivot>
            <PivotItem x:Uid="Settings_Personal">
                <StackPanel Margin="{StaticResource XSmallTopMargin}">
                    <TextBlock x:Uid="Settings_Personal_Firstname" />
                    <TextBox x:Uid="Settings_Personal_FirstnameBox" Text="{x:Bind ViewModel.Firstname, Mode=TwoWay}" />                        
                </StackPanel>
            </PivotItem>
        <Pivot>
</StackPanel>
```

My SettingsPage.xaml.cs:

```
public sealed partial class SettingsPage : Page
{
      public SettingsViewModel ViewModel { get; }

      public SettingsPage()
      {
         ViewModel = App.GetService<SettingsViewModel>();
         InitializeComponent();
      }

      public void BtnSave_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs routedEventArgs)
      {
         ViewModel.SetSetting();
      }
}
```

And my Viewmodel:

```
public class SettingsViewModel : ObservableRecipient
{
private string _firstname;

public string Firstname
{
    get => _firstname;
    set => SetProperty(ref _firstname, value);
}

public SettingsViewModel(ILocalSettingsService localSettingsService)
{
    _localSettingsService = localSettingsService;
}

public async Task SetSetting()
{
    string test = Firstname;  // < My Breakpoint
    await _localSettingsService.SaveSettingAsync("Firstname", Firstname);
}
```

}

At debug time, i'm filling the box with my firstname and set a brakpoint to the SetSettings Task. After clicking on the "Save" Button i can see, that Firstname is null.
Do i have to add some more code for gettings the information from the box?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `{x:Bind}` has a default mode of `OneTime`, you should set the `Mode` of the binding to `TwoWay` for your source property to get set as expected:

```
Text="{x:Bind ViewModel.Firstname, Mode=TwoWay}"
```